# How to remove "com.starfield.backupservice" from launchd?

Tags: macos, launchd

I remember sometime ago, I uninstall an application called starfield, but probably I didn't do a clean uninstall. Now in Console, I always see a annoying message:

> com.apple.launchd[1]  (com.starfield.backupservice[4441]) Exited with exit code: 1
>   com.apple.launchd[1]  (com.starfield.backupservice) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
>   com.apple.launchd[1]  (com.starfield.backupservice[4442])
>   posix_spawn("/Applications/Starfield/BackupService/offSyncService", ...): No such file or directory

I know it could be something wrong with my installation, how can I do a clean uninstall now, or just fix this issue, I don't want to see this message from my console any more.
Thanks.

Comment: Superuser.com ?

Answer (score 7):

**Unloading from `launchd`** by running the following in Terminal:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w com.starfield.backupservice
```

**Removing the configuration file:**

Look in `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/`, `/System/Library/LaunchDemons/`, `/Library/LaunchAgents/`, `/Library/LaunchDemons/` and `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` for a file by the name `com.starfield.backupservice.plist` and delete it.

Perform one or both of these steps.

Comment: AIUI, the "com.apple.launchd[1]" in the log indicates it's the system instance of launchd trying to start it, so it's a LaunchDaemon (not an Agent), so you need to use `sudo launchctl unload -w com.starfield.backupservice` to disable it.  Also, if you remove the config file without unloading it first, it'll actually keep trying to run until next reboot; so I'd recommend doing both steps.

Comment: @Gordon You're right of course, otherwise it's a line containing the user ID (e.g. 501).